# Docker Jenkins slave wrong character encoding

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, character-encoding, jenkins-agent

I'm using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/yasn77/docker-jenkins-slave/) Jenkins slave docker image, it is based on ubuntu:14.04

I would like to use a String Parameter which contains UTF-8 characters.

The charachers like `öüóőúűáéí` (Hungarian characters) will be replaced with question marks.

As [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8329) ticket mentions I tried to pass `-e LANG=hu_HU.UTF-8` and `bash -c "locale-gen hu_HU.UTF-8"` to Docker. I also placed `export LANG=hu_HU.UTF-8` in Jenkins user's `.bashrc`, but the characters are still being replaced. I also tried with `en_US.UTF-8`

I also tried to do the same with the Jenkins job:

```
+ export LANG=hu_HU.UTF-8
+ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=hu_HU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="hu_HU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The output is the same.

Comment: The locale should be installed on the jenkins host (http://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Than you, I  found the solution based on the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
bash -c "locale-gen hu_HU && locale-gen hu_HU.UTF-8 && update-locale &&  echo 'export LANG=hu_HU.UTF-8' > /jenkins/.bashrc"
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and perhaps cleaner) solution is to amend the Job configuration so that the environment variable is injected into the build job.

In the section Build Environment, add the environment variable in the 'Properties Content' field.

I think that this is a cleaner solution as the local jenkins account is not polluted leaving Jenkins installation to take care of the build environment; preferable when you have > 1 slave to maintain local accounts on...
This solution is accurate as of Jenkins ver1.613