# Jenkins launch agent via excution of command on the master caused jenkins job consule can't display emoji

Tags: docker, jenkins

My jenkins is running in a docker container & using `launch agent via excution of command on the master` connect to the slave. for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441671/jenkins-ssh-slave-disconnect-to-make-the-task-continue-perform)
Now my question is the jenkins job consule can't display the emoji & I have a ruby script to encode a Chinese url it return a wrong result. 
[image: here is the wrong error]
[image: this reuturn me a wrong url encode which is ???]
early when I use `Launch slave agent via SSH` it works well

How can I fix this question?

Comment: It seems to be an encoding console display issue, which is not configured to display UTF-8. DId you try also "Launch agent via Java Web Start"? What is console? A Mac shell?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327816/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43271877/6309

Comment: Sorry, the console is Jenkins job console output, I haven't try "Launch agent via Java Web Start" on a mac slave, In windows slave worked well

Comment: Yes, my two links could apply for the Jenkins job console too.